# Tektronix firmware XOR puzzle

Tags: xor, firmware-analysis

As a means of learning about packing firmware and for fun I am trying to unpack the latest firmware for an entry level Tektronix Function generator [firmware attached](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cN5qldL0jDh5B7_BdnHpTZQ9ivfeaOD1/view?usp=sharing)

I have read the forum and installed a REMnux VM.  I have also used the [XOR Cracker site](https://wiremask.eu/tools/xor-cracker/).

I have convinced myself the file is XORed and not encrypted using [binvis](http://binvis.io/#/) [image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mESOl.png)

The sites and the tools all concur as to probable XOR patterns, 94 94 90 a1 91 89 91 92 being the most likely.

I have also studied the excellent information available on [Malwarebytes](https://blog.malwarebytes.com/threat-analysis/2013/05/nowhere-to-hide-three-methods-of-xor-obfuscation/)

However, saving all combinations of XORed file I am unable to find and meaningful strings nor get binwalk to make any sense of the saved file.

Am I missing something?  Can anybody suggest any other strategy to yield the un-xored file?

Answer (score 3):

It is just addition/subtraction (mod 256).

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# These key bytes are the two's complement of the hex sequence mentioned in the question.
# The string appears twice in the decrypted blob, which makes me think it's what is used.
key = [ord(n) for n in "llp_owon"]

with open("AFG1022_V1.2.4.tfb", "rb") as infile:
  data = infile.read()
outdata=bytearray()
for n in range(0, len(data)):
  outdata.append((data[n]+key[n%len(key)])&0xff)
with open("decrypted.bin", "wb") as outfile:
  outfile.write(outdata)
```

Edit: Some extra information:

```
// all uint32_t values are little endian
struct section {
  uint32_t valid; // 0x00000001 if present, 0x00000000 if not
  uint32_t offset; // offset to beginning of this payload in this file
  uint32_t length; // length of this payload
  uint32_t crc32; // crc32 of the payload described by this section
};


// This is the header at the start of the firmware file
struct firmware_header {
  uint32_t crc32; // crc32 of file_contents[4:]
  uint8_t version[16]; // version string
  uint8_t package_type[12]; // package type string ("UpgradePack")
  section s[8]; // the payloads, see above for the structure
  uint8_t model[40]]; // hardware model
};

// Each section index accesses a specific path
const char *section_paths[8] = {
  "/flash/boot/fp",
  "/flash/boot/tx",
  "/flash/boot/bmp",  // splashscreen bitmap
  "/flash/boot/hz",
  "/flash/boot/os",   // load at address 0x00000000, ARM
  "/flash/boot/bios",
  "/flash/boot/menu",
  "/flash/boot/help",
};
```